# Simultaneous Xcode command-line builds with different Xcode-select values

Tags: xcode, bamboo

Our build server has multiple versions of Xcode installed.  Our build scripts use xcode-select to choose the correct version.  All that is fine.

Some of our builds take a while to run.  We're thinking of allowing multiple simultaneous builds (Bamboo agents) on the same build server.  My worry is that xcode-select on different (but simultaneous) builds would cause a race condition.  A build that begins with Xcode 9.4.1 might get switched to Xcode 10.0 mid-build if a second build begins and requires that version.

My only thoughts are to use VM's/new machines to parallelize the builds.

I'm curious if anyone's dealt with this scenario.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using xcrun instead of xcode-select to invoke your xcodebuilds. You may find your builds contending for system resources when building concurrently...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `DEVELOPER_DIR` environment variable rather than switching the active Xcode using `xcode-select`.

From the `xcode-select` man page:

> ### ENVIRONMENT
>
> `DEVELOPER_DIR`
>
> Overrides the active developer directory. When `DEVELOPER_DIR` is set, its value will be used instead of the system-wide active
>   developer directory.
>
> Note that for historical reason, the developer directory is considered to be the Developer content directory inside the Xcode
>   application (for example
>   **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer**). You can set the environment variable to either the actual Developer contents
>   directory,   or  the  Xcode  application  directory  --  the
>   `xcode-select` provided shims will automatically convert the 
>   environment variable into the full Developer content path.